# Total of a quantity in it's own column

Tags: sql

So say I have three columns. I need to write some SQL that gets me the total quantity.

[image: example of the data I need returned]

The first column comes from table A and the quantity column comes from table B.

Here is a continuation of the first question so say I have this table. I will go into detail about each field
[Second Query question table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwgFC.png)

- Item: from table a; is a unique number that has the same description but it will repeat based off of expiration date
- Description: from table b; is unique to each item number but only repeats cause the item does
- Total Qty: from table a; repeats the for the same item and is the total of all the different quantities of repeating item
- Hold Code: from table a; just appears sometimes isn't unique to certain items
- Quantity: from table a; can be the same for the same item number in seperate rows, normally isn't though
  -Expiration Date: from table a: is always different for every row, different for each item, and is order in ASC for each collection of the same item numbers.

How would I write the SQl for this Query????

Comment: the 'total quantity' is not a field and each item is unique (have other unique fields) even though they are labeled 1,1,1,2,2, etc.

Comment: Does table b have an item column that relates to tablea?

Comment: yes, table A and table B both have item fields/columns

Comment: Please edit the question and add the table definitions. Also, you should not use images but text because text can be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*, sum(quantity) over (partition by item) as total_quantity
from t;
```

Comment: . . . The first column comes from table A and the quantity column comes from table B.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.Item, (Select sum(Quantity) from TableB as c where a.Item= c.Item) as TotalQty,
b.Quantity
 from tableA as a
inner join TableB as b on a.Item= b.Item
```

this will work for ypu

Comment: The items might have the same numbers as an identifier. like say item 1 actually equals 10-00001 and item two is 10-00002 and item three is 10-00003. each item in each row is unique with an expiration date. Let me try this real quick. these are just three fields that are apart of a query that has 12 other fields and 3 other tables

Comment: "item" is in table a and b, "quantity" is in table b

Answer (score 0):

You need `JOIN` :

```
select a.item, b.quantity, sum(b.quantity) over (partition by a.item) as total_qty
from  table a inner join 
      table b
      on b.item = a.item;
```